# How to implement this kind of blur effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

As you can see , the background of the pop up box is in relatively black color and blur. How can i achieve the similar effect? Is the background blur effect use css to written or it is just a plain image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.overlay
{
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.5), rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.5) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7))
}
```

Source: Inspecting the element

Edit:

[Here's a link to a cross browser version](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+100&0+2,0.65+100;Custom)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do that with CSS3 gradients in HTML5, or you could use a transparent PNG.

Comment: You would want to use an `img` element, not a background, so you can size it to the browser window. It's pretty easy to do with jQuery.

Comment: thank you. my popup box must be fixed size? otherwise the img will overlap with the popup box